# First passage time for Compound Poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, stopping-times

Let $S$ follows a Compound Poisson distribution $(S \sim CP(\lambda,F_x(x))$, i.e. $$S = \sum_{i=0}^{N}X_i,$$ where $N\sim Po(\lambda)$ and $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} Exp(1)$.

I know that the first passage time $T \sim Exp(\lambda)$, but I am struggle to get the proof done.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am trying to proof that $T \sim Exp(\lambda)$.

Comment: What is the connection between $N$ and $T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof as follow:

\begin{align*}
        P(T>t)  &= 1 - P(T<t)\\
                &= 1 - \frac{1\times e^{-\lambda t}}{1!}\\
                &= 1 - e^{-\lambda t}
\end{align*}

Since $P(T>t)$ equal to the CDF of exponential distribution, therefore, $T \sim Exp(\lambda)$